# RelativeLayout Always at bottom

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to force a `RelativeLayout` to stay **ALWAYS** at the bottom of the screen so I wrote this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myFirstLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <!-- other view here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mySecondLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myFirstLayout" >

            <!-- Views -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- View here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutAtBottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mySecondLayout" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myLinearAtBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This code works when I can scroll (in this case stays at bottom) but when I can't scroll the layout it's below of the `mySecondLayout` but not at bottom. Why? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop the bottom linear out of the scroll view and eliminate the wrapped `RelativeLayout` to something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLinearAtBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myLinearAtBottom" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/myFirstLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <!-- other view here -->

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mySecondLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/myFirstLayout" >

                <!-- Views -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- View here -->

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/mySecondLayout"`  and try again .

Hope it works

Comment: I can't remove this because it's needed for see well the layout... other solution?

Comment: make changes in  android:id="@+id/mySecondLayout"  add android:layout_above="" and remove android:layout_below="@+id/mySecondLayout"

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this layout.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutAtBottom" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myFirstLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <!-- other view here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mySecondLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myFirstLayout" >

            <!-- Views -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- View here -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAtBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLinearAtBottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```